# How to fix a problematic earlier migration in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I wrote a Rails app locally and have maybe 10-15 migrations written. This all works fine locally.

When I wanted to deploy on heroku, I ran into a problem because they are using a earlier version of PostGreSQL than what I was using locally. One of my earliest migrations is failing because of a missing DB function in one of my database views.

I found out a way to hack around the DB function issue, but now I'm stuck because I can't write a new migration that changes the view to use the hack, since the rake db:migrate will abort after it hits the original problematic view creation.

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all drop your db:

```
heroku pg:reset
```

Then run your new migrations:

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

Comment: This works, but would cause a mismatch between your local environment and the production environment in terms of migrations. I also am guessing that you would also lose all the data in your production environment. But that wasn't a problem for me so I accept your answer.

Comment: You create the database for the first time and you do not have nothing to lose in production environment